# I Can't Start Managment Studio R2

Tags: database

I Have installed VS2010 and i have sleceted Server2008 to be installed, now in start menu i can only view the SQL Server 2008 but not SQL Server 2008 R2. How can I start it and work on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separately download SQL Server R2 2008 from the website.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650